# В чем отличие объявления типа с разной длиной?

Tags: база-данных, типы-данных

Рассмотрим два объявления типа столбца:

```
VARCHAR(20) и VARCHAR(150)
```

Кроме как ограничение данных по длине, чем-либо это различается? Например при втором варианте таблица будет весить больше, даже если все значения в столбцах NULL или еще что-нибудь такое?

Еще, например, частенько для указания типа, которое может быть либо истинно либо ложно - заводят столбец `TINYINT(1)`, а не `TINYINT(255)`. Ведь `TINYINT` занимает 1 байт в любом случае, разве нет?

В общем хотелось бы знать какие отличия в таких записях. В чем преимущество ограничение столбца, если он будет итак занимать столько байт, сколько указано в спецификации (как мне кажется). Загружается в память меньше или физически весят данные меньше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем и целом ответ дать трудно, поскольку способы реализации в разных СУБД могут отличаться. Отвечу на примере MySQL, поскольку есть [документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html), а также исходный код.

`VARCHAR` требует ровно столько байт, сколько сохраняет пользователь плюс байты на хранение длины строки. До длины 255 MySQL выделяет 1 байт, свыше 255 — 2 байта.

> Nullable-поле также требует одного бита в заголовке записи, но его можно не считать, поскольку он касается другого аспекта хранения.

Пустая строка '' для типа `VARCHAR(100)` будет занимать 1 байт (который будет хранить длину строки 0), а для типа `VARCHAR(300)` — 2 байта (которые также будут хранить длину строки 0, но уже для диапазона от 0 до 65535). Строка 'abcd' будет занимать 5 и 6 байт соответственно.

Таким образом, можно сэкономить 1 байт на запись, снизив длину `VARCHAR`-полей до 255 символов. Практически, это не имеет смысла, учитывая стоимость одного терабайта данных в облаках (порядка [10 долларов в год](http://www.topobzor.com/obzor-10-oblachnyx-xranilishh-dannyx/.html)).

Практичнее  опираться на предметную область и на удобство сопровождение `TINYINT(1)` говорит программисту, который видит код в первый раз, что мы храним булево значение, а не маленькое целое число. Он быстрее понимает назначение поля.

`VARCHAR(8000)` для хранения URL обосновано [стандартом RFC-7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1):

> It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of 8000 octets.

Comment: То есть в случае с `TINYINT` (mysql) даже если 100 миллионов записей то не зависимо от того, будет объявлено как (1) или как (255) - разницы в размере нет и это всего лишь для приемлемого восприятия?

Comment: Да. При этом восприятие гораздо важнее объёма. Экономия одного байта для ста миллионов записей&nbsp;&mdash; это 100 мегабайт. Стоимость&nbsp;&mdash; то ли сотые то ли тысячные цента в год. А вот то, что ваш коллега сразу поймёт, что именно вы имели в виду, когда писали код, это бесценно. Любой, кто разбирался с чужим кодом, поймёт.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.